Windows Subsystem for Linux - Network Configuration
I am working with windows subsystem for linux (Ubuntu 22.04.3) as an SSH client along with another Ubuntu VM.
For my work I need to have the same IP address in the two machines, but the problem seems to be that there is no netplan file i can configure, and when I type ip a, I get a random ip address
My question is why there is no netplan file controlling the networking configuration even though the netplan service is installed and is it possible to create a file and make it serve my needs considering the ip address without any issues ?

Please edit the question and add the version of Ubuntu you are using.

This question seems similar to: how to set/change a static IP in "Ubuntu on Windows" (WSL). If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
